# A strange question about echo output

Tags: php, echo

Look at the code below

```
echo "$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']";
```

it show 'Parse error', while the next shows ok

```
$str = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo "$str";
```

That was very  strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to refer an associative array inside of a string, you have to either add curly braces or remove quotes:
both

```
echo "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
echo "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
```

would work

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php <- **extremely useful reading**

Comment: Removing the quotes would trigger an undefined constant warning, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Rijk not inside a string literal. You can't access constants from inside a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

if you want to output `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, escape that dollar sign

```
echo "\$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']";
```

or put it into single quote

```
echo '$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]';
```

Clarification: You should not put only variables into quotes if you want content of actual variable, just delete these quotes and it will work

Comment: don't you see something strange in your latter example?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Fixed. By the way, I'm still waiting for you to accept the challenge in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282840/a-strange-question-about-echo-output/7282884#7282884). If you don't get it right without looking it up, I propose you remove the downvote there. If you know it from the top of your head (thus proving php's syntax rules are sufficiently simple), I'll promise I'll upvote your answer and be impressed of you ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, referring to variables inside a string literal is error-prone and should be avoided. Separate string literals from variables, and use single quotes whenever possible:

```
echo 'Host: header: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "\n";
```

If you *really* want to use complex [variable expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) inside string literals (and you shouldn't!), remove the inner quotes:

```
echo "Host header: $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
```

or surround the variable reference inside curly braces:

```
echo "Host header: {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
```

Comment: **nothing** error prone in referring to variables inside a string, as long as you follow simple PHP syntax rules

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Well, I'd say the very existence of this question shows otherwise. And I wouldn't call php's syntax rules simple - the [four different string literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) definitions simple. Quick (looking up is cheating!), what is the result of `strpos("\v", "v")`?

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you should use bracket to point out the variable range in string

```
echo "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
```

see also
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is detected in a double-quoted string, it will automaticly be converted to it's string value. But that's not every your case. the fact that the key of your array is also a string comes in conflict with the php parser. ex :

```
$ar = array("key" => "val");
echo "$ar['key']"; // won't work
echo "$ar[0]"; // will work because the key is not a string
```

Anyway, like others already said, the best solution is to encapsulate your variable in curly braces :

```
echo "{$ar['key']}";
```